# What is "Commodity Software"?

Tags: terminology, commodity

What is "Commodity Software"? (Part of the title in the article at http://valgrind.org/docs/newsome2005.pdf)

(I'm not an english speaker, and the direct translation of "commodity" to my language does not make much sense to me in a software-context.)

An example would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They appear to mean software that's available in a store, such as Windows, Photoshop, etc. The primary point seems to be analyzing some arbitrary piece of software without knowing anything about its internal structure, and without access to any source code.

Answer (score 8):

A commodity is an item that only distinguishes itself from competitors by price.  There are usually lots of suppliers of the item available, and none has a feature besides price that's different from others.

So commodity software would be widely available from many suppliers, and you wouldn't care which one you used; only price will make your choice.

Comment: This fits well with the "standard" definition of "commodity", but at least offhand I can think of virtually *no* software to which the definition would apply. The last thing anybody really wants is for their product to become a commodity, and software vendors have largely succeeded in keeping most competition based on features.

Comment: "The last thing anybody really wants is for their product to become a commodity" - I agree with this statement, but not your conclusion that there are NO commodities.  If you stay away from vendor-specific features, I'd say that Java EE app servers are (and should be) a commodity.  I can deploy a Spring app on Tomcat, Jetty, WebLogic, WebSphere, JBOSS, Glassfish, etc.  They're all commodities from that point of view.

Comment: I also agree with your definition.

Comment: I agree with duffymo´s definition, since it is wide enough yet applying to the paper context.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would agree with [duffymo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37213/duffymo)'s answer. But the way the author of the paper you cited uses the term the definition may mean "any software for which the source code is not readily available". In other words, the exploit detection techniques he outlines can be used on any compiled executable.

Comment: My definition is how an economist would define it.